# Getting MissingPluginException for image_picker plugin for flutter plugin

Tags: flutter

We have an android module that uses image_picker flutter plugin. It works fine when we run the flutter module. But when we integrate the flutter module with our android application, it gives the following exception.

**EXCEPTION:**

Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickMultiImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker_android)

[Yesterday 12:48 pm] Aswathi Nambiar
2022-08-08 12:37:51.812 15341-15515/com.oipa.companion.dev E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker_android)
    #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
    
    #1      ImagePickerAndroid.getImage (package:image_picker_android/image_picker_android.dart:161:26)

Tried all possible steps like

1. Invalidate caches
2. Flutter clean
3. and all the available answers on the internet.

Would appreciate for any leads.

Flutter version 3.0.5

Comment: This error of MissingPluginException usually appears right after adding new packages to ```pubspec.yaml``` and can be solved by just stop and rerun the project.

Comment: No, it is not working.. we have tried this several times. Another flutter module which was added to Android project using image_picker, is working fine. But this new flutter module using the same image_picker, is somehow not working..

Comment: if possible please add the code tat you're using to pick image

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved now.  In Android(with Kotlin), we used Fragment as a bridge to connect flutter module. After changing it to an Activity, it worked.